# CakePHP: log scopes

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've added this log configuration:

```
Log::config('users', [
    'className' => 'FileLog',
    'path' => LOGS,
    'levels' => [],
    'scopes' => ['users'],
    'file' => 'users.log'
]);
```

Now I'm trying to write, with something like this:

```
Log::warning(sprintf(
     '%s - Failed login with username `%s` and password `%s`',
     $this->request->clientIp(),
     $this->request->data('username'),
     $this->request->data('password')
), ['scope' => ['users']]);
```

or (it should be the same (or not?)):

```
Log::warning(sprintf(
     '%s - Failed login with username `%s` and password `%s`',
     $this->request->clientIp(),
     $this->request->data('username'),
     $this->request->data('password')
), 'users');
```

the problem is that the log is written in both `users.log` and `error.log`, while I would like that the log is written **only in the first** (`users.log`).

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The default configuration for CakePHP Log found in your `config/app.php` is:

```
// ...
'Log' => [
    // ...
    'error' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Log\Engine\FileLog',
        'path' => LOGS,
        'file' => 'error',
        'levels' => ['warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'],
    ],
    // ...
```

Which tells your app to write all "warning" level logs to `error.log`.

If you're doing custom logging, you might need to disable some defaults in order to meet your requirements

Comment: Ok, so I understand that this behavior is correct and this is the default. Yet, I do not seem proper that it should work as well. In short, if I want to write an error log into two different files, I can'tI?